# Почему после выхода из функции список не изменяется (даже с return)

Tags: python, python-3.x

Требуется вывести измененный список, где удалены нечетные числа, а четные целочисленно поделены пополам. (по условию функция не должна ничего возвращать, как и выводить (сделано для проверки))

```
def modify_list(l):
    l = list(filter(lambda x: not int(x) % 2, l))
    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] = l[i]//2

l = [10, 5, 8, 3]
modify_list(l)
print(l)
```

Comment: Потому что внутри функции у вас создается совершенно другой список, никак не связанный со внешним списком. Через return будет работать, если вы результат функции в ту же переменную запишите.

Comment: скопируйте сюда условия задачи

Comment: Напишите функцию modify_list(l), которая принимает на вход список целых чисел, удаляет из него все нечётные значения, а чётные нацело делит на два. Функция не должна ничего возвращать, требуется только изменение переданного списка

(в принципе я его (условие) описала уже)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну тогда просто идёте по индексам списка и делаете, что вас просят. Но есть один нюанс: по списку нужно идти с конца в начало, чтобы при удалении элемента из списка индексы не съезжали:

```
def modify_list(l):
    for i in range(len(l) - 1, -1, -1):
        if l[i] % 2:
            del l[i]
        else:
            l[i] //= 2

l = [10, 5, 8, 3]
modify_list(l)
print(l)
```

Вывод:

```
[5, 4]
```

Как вариант, обратный перебор индексов можно написать чуть более красиво так:

```
for i in reversed(range(len(l))):
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def modify_list(l_):
    global l
    l = list(filter(lambda x: not int(x) % 2, l))

    for i in range(len(l)):
        l[i] = l[i] // 2


l = [10, 5, 8, 3]
modify_list(l)
print(l)
```

Comment: во, совсем другое дело :)

Comment: я прохожу эту задачу на курсе и у меня высвечивается ошибка о том, что функция должна принимать хотя бы 1 аргумент и тогда данный код не подходит

Comment: Ну да, судя по условию задачи нельзя так вот через `global` её решать.

Comment: на курсе задачи задают по какой либо теме! что вы проходили недавно?